# How to build FPS controls with Three.js in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Currently I'm trying to build a small 3D FPS Game with Three.js. But I need some help with the controls.

To explain what I wanna do this Video will show you exactly my wanted result (just the controls, not the world):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WDDJDTeTBc4

I can't find any open source examples or tutorials about this controls, so I ask here for some help. What I exactly have to do?

I thougth about something like the following, but maybe it's not the best (fast) way:
- Pointerlock the mouse (how can I change the camera 'rotation'?), moving the mouse = watching around
- Key controls (W, A, S, D to move)
- Character (just a simple sphere geometry) behind the camera

Will this be the right way? Controls like in Minecraft, with a Character right behind the camera. Any ideas? I'm happy about every comment that will help me.

Comment: Have you looked into these? https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/examples/js/controls

Comment: @BrendanAnnable: Yes, of course. I use the PointerlockControls, but I stuck at "moving the character (simple sphere geometry) behind the camera.

Comment: Maybe you should use `FirstPersonControls` not `PointerlockControls` ?

Comment: @Wilt: FirstPersonControls sounds right, but is wrong for my final goal. PointerlockControls are like FPS Controls.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that. I added an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to move the object (your character) around with the camera it will be as simple as adding the object to the camera or adding the camera to your object...

So something like:

```
var character = ...

var camera.add(character);

var controls = new THREE.PointerLockControls(camera);
```

This is not tested, but you get the idea.

You can see [the source code of your example](http://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html) for other details.

Comment: That's good, my object moves a little bit laggy but that's okay. What  'bout the Raycaster? I have the position of my controls: controls.getObject().position returns a Vector3. But the raycaster from this vector to the same vector (y - 1) don't work. I just got a plane (rotated) under the controls.

Comment: If you want to know about raycaster there are also a lot of helpful examples on the Three.js website. Otherwise post another question about your raycasting issues.